# Product structure

Tags: 8, commerce

While building a demo webshop for wine, I am not sure about how the product structure should be.
So, I have to map the next structure and I am not sure what is the right approach.

For example, we have wine as product, which could be Chardonnay/Riesling or Cabernet. It could also differ in sizes (1L, 1.5L, 2L) and every product would have their own images.

What is the right approach for the structure? Which would be a product type, which would be a product variation and which would be a product attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Your products variations are the bottles you are going to put in a box a deliver to a customer. They have an unique sku and a price. Starting with that, you should choose how they are going to be shown in the store view. In my case I chose two attributes. One for the year (vintage) and one for the size (1L, 1.5L, ...). Every product variation has its own score (Parker o J.Peñin), tasting, pairing, but the products has the shared properties like producer, country, region, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Commerce** gives you a lot of flexibility actually and might get confusing

I see 2 basic setups:

1. **wine** *product type* and **wine type** and **size** *attributes* and attach them to the wine *product variation type*.  This way you would probably add images to the *variation type* and you would create wine *variations* specifying unique image, SKU, title, type for each variation.  Typically with this setup all wine variations are displayed as 1 product and when changing an attribute dropdown the wine variation details (price, image etc) would appear without page refresh.  I would choose this setup if I wanted to display all variations as one product.
2. **Wine** *product* with just 1 *variation*, image could be a part of the *product* or *variation*.  You then would create individual **wine** *products* specifying price, SKU, image and other details. This way **wines** would display as **individual items** in a catalog view.  And would choose this setup for this exact reason.  No *attributes* are needed in this setup.

Of course you can make other combinations from the solutions above with **type** or **size** not setup as attribute or with image being part of product or product variation.

There is probably other ways to setup products using contrib modules from drupal.org.